# ClickEvent (or query selector) does not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

I am trying to build small calculator using HTML/CSS and JS.

The thing is that when I am trying to select buttons of the calculator from HTML script and add EventListener to them, they are not working properly. Here is part of my HTML:

```
`<table class="table1">
            <tr>
                <td id="n-1">1</td>
                <td id="n-2">2</td>
                <td id="n-3">3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="n-4">4</td>
                <td id="n-5">5</td>
                <td id="n-6">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="n-7">7</td>
                <td id="n-8">8</td>
                <td id="n-9">9</td>
            </tr>
        </table>`
```

And here is my event function:

```
document.querySelector(.table1 td).addEventListener('click',function(){
        console.log('It works');
        var z = this.value;
        console.log(z);
    });
```

The only time I am receiving the console output is when I click on first cell of table (1). I am not sure why when I click on the other cells (for example 3 or 7) this do not work.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to use a query. `querySelectorAll()` and loop/iterate through the node list returned to add your event listeners . Here is a [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/New_To_JS/zcso8L3v/) Also `<td>` do not have a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`querySelector()` Only returns one element, in your case it returns the first `td` inside `.table1`
If you want to add the listener to all td's you must use `querySelectorAll()`:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.table1 td').addEventListener('click',function(){
    .... // The rest of your code
});
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll